# jsqmessagesviewcontroller like elagant message library for android

Tags: android, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to create a messaging app and want to use any existing messaging library for doing so. I found Jsqmessagesiviewcontroller library for IOS which is open source and is pretty easy to use. However, I am not able to find any similar library for Android. Does anyone knows about any messaging library present for android is open source and can be easily modified and customized for different use cases?
NOTE: I have found, https://github.com/guardianproject/ChatSecureAndroid, which looks promising but would like to know if there more options to consider.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you found something similar?

Comment: I couldn't find any open source library and finally moved to below react-native based chat library for ios and android both,
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat

Answer (score 8):

We're just released JSQMessagesViewController-like library to create UI for chats. Check it out on GitHub:
http://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found another project:
https://atlas.layer.com/android
It's 100% OpenSource